# How to Send Emails With reactjs Using Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, nodemailer, amazon-ses

i want to connect my simple **REACTJS** contact form to my AWS SES email to receive emails
I did some researches about this but did not find a useful tutorial or article to follow it

is there anyone who can help!?
THANKS

Comment: React is for Frontend and all the AWS part is on a backend. How do you plan to connect AWS to your React service? Where do you run your react app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tutorial to do just what you asked for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HiHflLTqiwU

In short: You set up an AWS IAM user with limited permissions to AWS SES. The user has only programmatic access to the AWS console. You will use the secret key and key ID in your React app later on, so make sure to save it. Also, make sure you are familiar with the [SES pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing)

Then, go ahead and configure AWS SES to your needs.

Your React App will need to run with an [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/) backend. Add the [JavaScript AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/) to your project. It is needed to connect to AWS and interact with SES. Here the link to the [AWS SES SDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html)

The tutorial is great. However, there are some things to look out for:

- Make sure you don't check in your access key and secret to a VCS.
- The AWS access key will never be renewed. This can be ok but should be avoided

  > Regularly rotating your IAM credentials helps prevent a compromised set of IAM access keys from accessing components in your AWS account. Rotating IAM credentials is also an important part of security best practices in IAM. ([Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/automatically-rotate-iam-user-access-keys.html))
- You send e-mails through a public, unauthenticated POST request to your express backend. Anybody with their browser's devtools open can see the POST request. including the headers, the request body, and repsonse. With Postman, or a similar tool, anybody can spam your contact endpoint. To avoid that you can setup rate limits, put an API Gateway, with quotas in the middle instead of calling SES directly, etc.